# Allowing both user and administrator to login through a single page using slim php

Tags: php

How do I allow both user and administrator to login through the same page but redirect to different pages using slim php and mysql database e.g

```
if(sid = 0) {
    //redirect to admin dashboard}
else if (sid = 1) {
    //redirect to user dashboard}
```

Comment: Pretty much like in your example. When you get the userdata from the database to validate the credentials, check if it is an admin or an user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `header` function to execute the re-direct and assuming for instance you have a database column called admin that will be 1 for yes, or 0 for no you could do the following.

```
if($row['admin'] == 1) // if admin, load this url - otherwise load second url
{
    header('Location: http://www.google.com/');
}
else 
{
    header('Location: http://www.stackoverflow.com/');
}
```